# Magento: How to get thumbnail?

Tags: php, magento, csv, datafeed

I downloaded a script to create a CSV datafeed of my products and I would also like to include a url to the thumbnail. The code already has the following for the product image url:

`$product_data['ImageURL']=Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'catalog/product'.$product->getImage();`

So I tried to adjust this to:

`$product_data['ThumbnailURL']=Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'catalog/product'.$product->getThumbnail();`

Which displays exactly the same image url (not the thumb). How would I fix this?

I did a `var_dump($product);` and the result was:

`["image"]=> string(18) "/f/i/file_2_18.png" ["small_image"]=> string(18) "/f/i/file_2_18.png" ["thumbnail"]=> string(18) "/f/i/file_2_18.png"`

I also need to get the subcategory for the product but I don't know how to call this. How can I see which variables are possible? E.g. `$product->getPrice` or `$product->getName`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288340/get-original-image-url-magento-1-6-1-0/8288805#8288805

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recently needed to do this as well... here's how I got to it:

```
$_product->getMediaGalleryImages()->getItemByColumnValue('label', 'LABEL_NAME')->getUrl();
```

**Or another example**

You should use the catalog product media config model for this purpose.

```
<?php

//your code ...

echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')
            ->getMediaUrl( $product->getImage() ); //getSmallImage(), getThumbnail()
```

**Edit After your comment.**

**Update Answer**

**See below URL**

[Make all store images the base, small and thumbnail images in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349592/make-all-store-images-the-base-small-and-thumbnail-images-in-magento)

**Try it**

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
foreach ($products as $product) {
    if (!$product->hasImage()) continue;
    if (!$product->hasSmallImage()) $product->setSmallImage($product->getImage());
    if (!$product->hasThumbnail()) $product->setThumbnail($product->getImage());
    $product->save();
}
```

Hope that helps you!

Comment: Wow, what a great answer... :-)

Comment: Problem is that I get the exact same image when I echo `Image` `Thumbnail` or `SmallImage`. Is this then just a problem with my store?

Comment: See below URL it is help full. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474117/how-to-get-a-products-image-in-magento

Comment: I have update my answer after you above comment. please take a look. And see also this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349592/make-all-store-images-the-base-small-and-thumbnail-images-in-magento

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see which data you can access you could try this:

```
<?php var_dump(array_keys($product->getData())); ?>
```

You can then use two methods to get this data:

```
<?php $product->getAttributeName() // Use CamcelCase ?>
```

or

```
<?php $product->getData('attribute_name') // underscores ?>
```

Comment: `Varien_Object::debug()` offers a bit more utility and insight.