# Magento - Auto set base, small and thumbnail on upload

Tags: magento, upload, image-uploading

Morning,

We have literally searched all over Stackoverflow and Google to find this solutions but still don't have the right answer.

We're trying to auto-set the `Base, Small and Thumbnail` options on the `first uploaded image, so when uploading multiple images the first image will always have all three options checked`.

If anyone has tried and succeeded with find this answer and advice, Thank you.

[image: Catalog Product]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very easy. Example's [here](http://jsfiddle.net/P0ZiTR0N/howhffyc/). Replace in `root/js/mage/adminhtml/product.js` in the end of `handleUploadComplete` around 120 row code

```
    this.container.setHasChanges();
    this.updateImages();
},
updateImages : function() {
```

with

```
    this.container.setHasChanges();
    this.updateImages();
    $$('tr#media_gallery_content-image-1 td.cell-image.a-center input')[0].setAttribute('checked','checked');
    $$('tr#media_gallery_content-image-1 td.cell-small_image.a-center input')[0].setAttribute('checked','checked');
    $$('tr#media_gallery_content-image-1 td.cell-thumbnail.a-center input')[0].setAttribute('checked','checked');
},
updateImages : function() {
```

And enjoy autoselect first image after upload

Answer (score 0):

If you have already uploaded your images and need to set the first one as thumb/base/small try the sql command in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11826300/3376305):

Just follow the instructions given by stereo_world and nhahtdh and then refresh your cache.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Fabian and Doug for the groundwork](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/30743/142). I just published an extension, which does exactly what you are trying to achieve in a clean way: https://github.com/customgento/CustomGento_AutoSelectImages

It simply adds a JS file on the admin product edit page. In the JS file, the mentioned method `Product.Gallery.createImageRow` is wrapped, so that the radio buttons can be selected after the first image has been uploaded. Here is the JS "magic":

```
if (typeof Product.Gallery !== 'undefined') {
    Product.Gallery.prototype.createImageRow = Product.Gallery.prototype.createImageRow.wrap(function (parentMethod, image) {
        // first call the parent method
        parentMethod(image);

        // auto-select the radio buttons for the first uploaded image
        $H(this.imageTypes).each(function (pair) {
            if (this.images.length === 1) {
                this.getFileElement(image.file, 'cell-' + pair.key + ' input').checked = true;
            }
        }.bind(this));
        this.setProductImages(image.file);
    });
}
```